# How can I check the question mark is at the end of the input field using javascript Vue?

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to check if the question mark "?" is present or not at the end of the question using *Vuejs*, but how can I use *if/else* condition.

---

[[image: ]]

Comment: `someString.indexOf('?') >= 0` or `someString.includes('?')` - of course, `someString` has to be the *value* of the input - but since all you've shown is a pretty picture, I guess you must be all over that

Comment: yeah it works @JaromandaX

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length of the string and use `charAt` to get the last character

```js
function test() {
  let getVal = document.getElementById('ip').value;
  let lastChar = getVal.charAt(getVal.length - 1)
  if (lastChar === "?") {
    console.log("? at end of string")
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ip">
<button type="button" onclick="test()">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can use `lastIndexOf` method of a string object. The following method will return `-1` if there is no `'?'` at the end of the string:*

```
 function test(str) {
      return str.lastIndexOf("?") 
    }
```